# Debian Stretch / Gnome - my laptop screen just rotated; need to get back to normal

Tags: debian, gnome, display-settings

So I accidentally tilted a laptop (HP ZBook) under Gnome Shell (Debian Stretch), and to my surprise the screen rotated automatically, so I have portrait 1080x1920 now. Funnily, I can tilt the laptop to the opposite side, and the system performs a 180 degree rotation. Only, the sensor or the software doesn't detect when I tilt back to normal, so I'm stuck with a 90 degree rotated portrait format.

Gnome display preferences doesn't have any rotation option, and xrandr doesn't indicate that the screen is rotated. How do I fix this?

---

Note that reboot solved it, but I would like to know how I can get back to unrotated screen in a live session if this happens again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, I can use a special key on the laptop keyboard, <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>f4</kbd> which puts the screen back upright.