# Debian Stretch / Gnome: disable sensor-based screen rotation

Tags: debian, gnome, sensors

I still have a constant [problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350668/) of an HP Zbook screen being randomly rotated by Gnome based on some bad sensor data in the laptop. While I can rotate back with <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>f4</kbd>, this often causes applications to crash, etc.

I would like **to disable the auto-rotation feature** altogether. How can I turn off this thing?

Comment: Your Q seems to be a duplicate of [stop gnome auto-rotate screen when shake laptop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/330194). Read the comments there for the solution.

Comment: Search for lock orientation in the dash and just click it to lock and unlock

Answer (score 10):

The setting to use is

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active false
```

Comment: On Debian 10 Buster, use this setting: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock true` as explained in [Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 screen orientation spontaneously changes](https://askubuntu.com/a/876606/315347). In Debian 10 you can also simply "lock orientation" in the Dash as explained in another comment.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the rotation sensor with the following commands:

> sudo systemctl stop iio-sensor-proxy.service
>
> sudo systemctl disable iio-sensor-proxy.service

or

> sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy

Comment: It worked, thanks! The last one is perhaps my favourite solution.